# AddPrinter() sets the new printer as default. How to avoid it?

Tags: winapi

After calling WinAPI's [`AddPrinter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343.aspx) function, the newly created printer is set as the default printer. I don't want that - I want the default printer to remain as it was.

So do I just have to get the default printer before calling [`AddPrinter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343.aspx) and then restore it afterwards?

I couldn't find any parameter that controls this behavior.

Comment: Just use `GetDefaultPrinter` and `SetDefaultPrinter` to save and restore the previous default.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, that's doable, but this solution looks a bit awkward to me..

Comment: Looks like this behaviour is new to Windows 10 and can be disabled by the user, see http://blogs.msmvps.com/bradley/2015/12/29/introducing-windows-10-into-your-essentials-2012-r2-network/